effector createStore with generic State gives: TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'
I am creating event and store:
import {createEvent, createStore} from 'effector';

export default function createEventAndStore<T = {}>() {
  const myEvent = createEvent<T>()
  // TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  // 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.
  const myStore = createStore<T>({})
  myStore.on(myEvent, (_, next) => next)
}

And getting error:
TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.
Is it ok to cast to T: const myStore = createStore<T>({} as T) or is there a better way to fix it?

Well, this error occurs because {} might not necessarily match T
type ObjectWithRequiredKeys = {requiredKey: bool}

createEventAndStore<ObjectWithRequiredKeys>()

then obviously {} would not contain the requiredKey. Presumably, you are also getting these events and stores later, then you could reach an errorful state where you attempt to access a key when you haven't set it yet.
The idiomatic rule of generic functions is that if you are using a generic type, it should be bound to a parameter in some way.
export default function createEventAndStore<T = {}>(t: T) {
  const myEvent = createEvent<T>()
  const myStore = createStore<T>(t)
  myStore.on(myEvent, (_, next) => next)
}

If you don't have an initial value, the store can be a union of T | undefined. Note I've added a return type just to assert a tuple type rather than the implicit (EventCallable<T> | StoreWritable<T | undefined>)[]
import {createEvent, createStore, EventCallable, StoreWritable} from 'effector';

// you don't necessarily need a paramter, this is an optional parameter
// provided for demonstration purposes
function createEventAndStore<T = {}>(t?: T): [event: EventCallable<T>, store: StoreWritable<T | undefined>] {
  const myEvent = createEvent<T>()
  // we need skipVoid to accept undefined as a value
  // https://effector.dev/en/api/effector/createstore/#methods-createStore-defaultState-config-arguments
  const myStore = createStore<T | undefined>(t, {skipVoid: false})
  myStore.on(myEvent, (_, next) => next)
  return [myEvent, myStore];
}

You could also do a union of T | {}, but I think undefined makes more clear that the store has not been set to anything yet, whereas {} you'll have to check Object.keys(...) to determine if you have all your fields. Likewise T | null would work.
View on Effector Playground
